# Module Import from tkinter Widget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-import

Not long ago I asked an question on how to import from an input statement. Nailed it. Now I'm upgrading my lengthy code to a GUI for the user. Same problem. How do I import a module based on user input from the tkinter widget Entry.
I originally had:

```
var1=__import__(input("Enter a module: "))
```

And attempted something like this:

```
import tkinter
var1=__import__(tkinter.Entry(top, bd=5)).pack()
```

A few different phrasings all resulted in the basic error:

```
TypeError: __import__() argument 1 must be str, not Entry
```

I have a few different methods still on my list to try. For example:

```
var1=Entry(top, bd=5).grid(row=7)
var2=Entry.get(var1)
var=__import__(var2)
```

This gives me the rather awful error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python33\Doc\Project\testing.py", line 21, in finish
    var2=Entry.get(var1)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2512, in get
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `Entry` **instance** to work with it.

This way:

```
my_entry = Entry(top, bd=5) # you get object (Entry instance)
my_entry.grid(row=7) # you call object method grid()

entry_text = my_entry.get() # you call object method get()

var = __import__(entry_text)
```

---

**BTW:**

This way you get result of grid() function, not Entry instance.

```
var1 = Entry(top, bd=5).grid(row=7) # grid() returns always None
```

see

```
my_entry = Entry(top, bd=5)
grid_result = my_entry.grid(row=7) # grid() returns always None
var1 = grid_result
```

---

In this code you try to pack() imported library :)

```
var1 = __import__(tkinter.Entry(top, bd=5)).pack()
```

see

```
my_entry = Entry(top, bd=5) # you get object 
imported_library = __import__(my_entry) # object can't be argument for __import__
var1 = imported_library.pack() # you can't pack library
```

Comment: You should mention that your code, as written, won't work. You might want to mention the import needs to be done in response to an event such as a button click, pressing enter, etc. If you call .get() immediately after creating the widget you'll always get the empty string. I know that's obvious to you, but it might not be to the OP.

Comment: I messed around enough with my other theories to understand the need for a button(or other method), but thank you. I dont have the time right now to try this, but as soon as I do I'll share the results. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, works great. At first I had an issue addressing a variable within the imported module, then I realized I was being stupid. Works like a charm.